# TLSharp function GetHistoryAsync returns only 100 last messages

Tags: c#, telegram

I have 2714 new messages in Telegram chat. I call GetHistoryAsync with "limit" parameter equals to 10000, but function returns only 100 last messages. Does anybody know whether it TLSharp error or Telegram protocol restriction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't get more than 100 pieces of messages/views/... in 1 request, but you can play with max_id and offset, to get specific 100 messages.

```
public async Task<TLAbsMessages> GetHistoryAsync(TLAbsInputPeer peer, int offset, int max_id, int limit)
```